# HTML5: How do I get 2 videos on the same page?

Tags: css, html, video

I'm trying to display two videos with controls next to each other but I can't seem to get it to work. I can have one of them, but not the other. I've tried if I directed to the file incorrectly but nope, everything seems to check out.

```css
@fontface {
  font-family: Halo;
  src: url(fonts/Halo.ttf);
}
body {
  background-image: url(images/background-image/ExuberantWitness.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#head {
  font-family: Halo;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.leftVideo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
}
.rightVideo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HaloPLAY</title>
  <link href="Trailer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <a href="index.html">
    <img style="margin: 0px auto;display:block" src="images/title/Halo.jpg" width="750" height="100">
  </a>
  <h1 id="head">WATCH THE TRAILER TO LEARN MORE</h1>
  <div class="leftVideo">
    <video width="500" height="350" controls>
      <source src="video/Halo5Trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/Halo5Trailer.ogg" type="video/ogg">
          </class>
          <div class="rightVideo">
            <video width="500" height="350" controls>
              <source src="video/Halo5Trailer2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="video/Halo5Trailer2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                  </class>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
</class>
```

To

```
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have unclosed tags and closes a tag that doesnt exsist `</class>`.

Try it like this:

```
<div class="leftVideo">
    <video width="500" height="350" controls>
    <source src="video/Halo5Trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/Halo5Trailer.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
<div class="rightVideo">
     <video width="500" height="350" controls>
     <source src="video/Halo5Trailer2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="video/Halo5Trailer2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     </video>
</div>
```

Please look here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp for more information.

Greeting,

Alex